# how to parse huge amount of json data parsing in php?

Tags: php, json

I am getting the huge json data from the webservice and parsing through loop.but loop makes my website slow.Is there any other ways to fetch the json data in php?.
This is my snippet.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($trid) ; $i++) { 
$operator_aval=operator_routes_a($trid[$i],$Fromd);
$page1=file_get_contents($operator_aval);
$data1=json_decode($page1,true);
$opr_res=count($data1['routes']);
for ($j=0; $j < count($data1['routes']); $j++) {          
$origin=$data1['routes'][$j]['route']['origin'];
$destination=$data1['routes'][$j]['route']['destination'];
$status=$data1['routes'][$j]['route']['status'];
$service_name=$data1['routes'][$j]['route']['operator_service_name'];
// echo $origin."--".$destination."<br>";
if(($Fromname==$origin) && ($Toname==$destination) &&($status!="Unavailable-Service Left" ||  $status!="Unavailable-Cancelled")&& $service_name!=""){
    echo 'trid : '.$trid[$i].'reservation id : '.$data1['routes'][$j]['route']['reservation_id']."---".$data1['routes'][$j]['route']['travels']."<br>";
    $count++;
         }

}     
 }
```

Comment: Try with `json_decode` and then go with PHP's powerful array operations

Comment: Let us know what is your input and what is your output

Comment: we are using json _decode only and traverse the array through 'for' loop.But it is taking too long to dispaly.

Comment: Our input is large amount of json data.depending on the condition we are displying some of the required json data from huge json data

Comment: there is for loop inside for, check if you can avoid that. Also in for loop you are doing file_get_contents which will take most of your time. Also try to limit the data from  webservice, usually most provide limit functionality